# How could i refresh a list once an item has been removed from a list within a list in python

Tags: python, list, split

This is quite complicated but i would like to be able to refresh a larger list once at item has been taken out of a mini list within the bigger list.

```
listA = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','6','8','9','5','3','7']
```

i used the code below to split it into lists of threes

```
split = [listA[i:(i+3)] for i in range(0, len(listA) - 1, 3)]

print(split)

# [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['6','8','9'],['5','3','7']]

split = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['6','8','9'],['5','3','7']]
```

if i deleted `#3` from the first list, split will now be

```
del split[0][-1]
split = [['1','2'],['4','5','6'],['6','8','9'],['5','3','7']]
```

after `#3` has been deleted, i would like to be able to refresh the list so that it looks like;

`split = [['1','2','4'],['5','6','6'],['8','9','5'],['3','7']]`

thanks in advance

Comment: So you won't recalculate it each time?

Comment: Could you tell us a little background on why do you need that?

Comment: @RikPoggi: i need this for turning of cards in the deck in a solitaire game. Also, removing the card that is currently being displayed. However, my game is to be played in the python shell.

Comment: @CodeBisector: You shouldn't do it that way, a generator that will yield 3 cards at a time will be much better.

Comment: @RikPoggi: which generator would that be?

Comment: @CodeBisector: I've added an answer, with an example on how you could deal your cards 3 by 3 without caring on how long is your deck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how big this list is getting, but you would need to flatten it and recalculate it:

```
>>> listA = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','6','8','9','5','3','7']
>>> split = [listA[i:(i+3)] for i in range(0, len(listA) - 1, 3)]
>>> split
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['6', '8', '9'], ['5', '3', '7']]
>>> del split[0][-1]
>>> split
[['1', '2'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['6', '8', '9'], ['5', '3', '7']]
>>> listA = sum(split, []) # <- flatten split list back to 1 level
>>> listA
['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '6', '8', '9', '5', '3', '7']
>>> split = [listA[i:(i+3)] for i in range(0, len(listA) - 1, 3)]
>>> split
[['1', '2', '4'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['8', '9', '5'], ['3', '7']]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need this for turning of cards in the deck in a solitaire game.

You can deal your cards using [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a good key function:

```
def group_key(x, n=3, flag=[0], counter=itertools.count(0)):
    if next(counter) % n == 0:
        flag[0] = flag[0] ^ 1
    return flag[0]
```

`^` is a [bitwise operator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), basically it change the value of the flag from `0` to `1` and viceversa. The flag value is an element of a list because we're doing some kind of memoization.

Example:

```
>>> deck = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '6', '8', '9', '5', '3', '7']
>>> for k,g in itertools.groupby(deck, key=group_key):
...     print(list(g))
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['6', '8', '9']
['5', '3', '7']
```

Now let's say you've used card '9' and '8', so your new deck looks like:

```
>>> deck = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '6', '5', '3', '7']
>>> for k,g in itertools.groupby(deck, key=group_key):
...     print(list(g))
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['6', '5', '3']
['7']
```

Comment: How could you put this in one function.

Comment: @CodeBisector: Just put the for-loop into a function that accept a `deck` as argument and `yield list(g)` instead of `print` and use it like a generator (iterator). Otherwise make it `return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(deck, key=group_key)]`. The choice is up to you.

Comment: @CodeBisector: I don't really know how your game looks like, so feel free to overlook what I'm about to tell you, but I'd say that you might want to put this code inside a `deal` method of some `Deck` class or something.

Answer (score 2):

Just recreate the single list from your nested lists, then re-split.

You can join the lists, assuming they are only one level deep, with something like:

```
rejoined = [element for sublist in split for element in sublist]
```

There are no doubt fancier ways, or single-liners that use itertools or some other library, but don't overthink it. If you're only talking about a few hundred or even a few thousand items this solution is quite good enough.

Comment: A simpler way to join is `sum(foo, [])`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: true, though I think it makes for misleading code since you aren't actually summing something. OTOH, list comprehensions like what I showed are hard to grok at first glance. Probably the most obvious way is to use `itertools.chain`, but I'm not a fan of pulling in a whole module for one line of code when you can get the work done with built-in functions. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Build an object that contains a list and tracks when the list is altered (probably by controlling write to it), then have the object do it's own split every time the data is altered and save the split list to a member of the object.